# Unable to change form field name in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have this form in CakePHP:

```
echo $form->input('name', array('label' => $j['contact_name']));
echo $form->input('email', array('class' => 'disabled', 'label' => $j['contact_mail']));
echo $form->end(__('Submit', true));
```

I have two different languages, so I want to change name into name, but when I do that it doesn't work. Anybody help me how will this work in CakePHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to change the 'name' of the input or the visible 'label'? Does the value have to be stored in a different column in the database?

Comment: I just need to visible label, name to namn

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the 'Localization' features of CakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Basically, any string that should be translated in the current language, should be echoed via the `__()` method, for example `echo __('hello')`

The string 'hello' in this example is the string to be localised (translated). CakePHP uses GNU locale files to define your translations. In these files are 'pairs' of strings, called `msgid` (the string/message to be translated) and `msgstr` (the translated string). Each language ('locale') has its own translation file, located in:

```
app/Locale/[locale]/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

For example, to have a 'Dutch' translation (locale 'nld'), this file:

```
app/Locale/nld/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

Should be created, containing:

```
msgid  "hello"
msgstr "hallo"
```

Now, by switching the locale to 'nld' (for example in the `beforeFilter()` of your AppController;

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'nld');
```

The 'nld' locale will be used and this line;

```
echo _('hello');
```

Will output:

```
hallo
```

In your case, setting the label would be something like this;

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => __('hello')));
```

**important**

older versions (before CakePHP 2.x) 'echoed' the translated string in stead of *returning* the translated string. To *return* the translated string in CakePHP 1.x, you need to pass 'true' as second parameter; `echo __('hello', true);`

Strings in .po files are **case sensitive**, e.g. `Hello !== hello`

Locale files are meant for 'short', fixed text in your application, not to translate big pieces of text or 'dynamic' text, entered by the user. although it *is* possible to use it for these situations, it is not *designed* for this.

There are several other changes between CakePHP 2.x and 1.x, so in all cases, make yourself familiar with the whole concept by reading the manual.

Comment: I have same thing in .po file like this but i don't know why its not translating.....#: /views/themed/pages/contact.ctp:39

msgid "Name *"
msgstr "Namn *"

Comment: Ehm, you're saying that msgid and msgstr are in your .ctp file? Are you sure the '*' are part of the 'label' not a separate text/element? Please take one step at a time start, for example, with a simple 'hello' to translate and continue from that on.